# Life Long Gentile searching for my Jewish roots

Tags: gentiles, adult-learning

I was born and raised as Gentile; after my Fathers death I am now questioning the teachings I received about life after death.  I am very eager to learn the foundational teachings of Judaism.  Can someone recomend a starting point?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya!

I recommend that you start by looking at [JewFAQ](http://www.jewfaq.org/), which covers basic ideas of Judaism in a well-organized way, and includes articles that are written specifically for beginners as well as articles that are more in-depth. They also include helpful to other resources for further reading. [Here](http://www.jewfaq.org/olamhaba.htm) is their article on the afterlife.

If you have questions about what you're reading, you are welcome to post them here.

Comment: [_Baruch shekivanta!_](/a/10741)